# CollapsingToolbarLayout + NestedScrollView with D-Pad

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, d-pad

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with a `NestedScrollView` that contains a TextView with a lot of content. 
Everything works fine on touch devices, but I'm unable to scroll the view using a D-Pad controller. In fact I can scroll the layout up and down about an inch but not more, even if there's a lot more content to display. Here's my layout. The `TextView` with id=description contains the content that needs to be scrolled.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLight">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/appBarHeight"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/appBarHeight"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:focusable="true">

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/description"
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:minHeight="0dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks.